# Wrapping a C++ class for export to a dynamic language using variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I've solved this problem without variadic templates, but wanted to see if there was a cleaner solution that uses them.  I'm exporting a large number of classes to Google's V8 Javascrpt engine and am building a compile time DSL to make the job less painful.

The key questions is:  Is it possible to type match a template pack against a runtime list of dynamic strong typed values and call the appropriate c++ method/constructor.

Consider the class X:

```
struct X {
    X(int32_t x=42) {cout << "X(" << x << ")" << endl; }
    X(bool x, double y) {cout << "X(" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl; }

    void Do1() { cout << "Do1()" << endl; }
    int Do2(double x, int32_ty=0) { cout << "Do2()" << endl; return 99; }
}
```

The wrapper looks like:

```
Wrap<X>("X")
    .Constructor<Opt<int32_t>>()
    .Constructor<bool_t,double>()
    .Method<&X::Do1>("Do1")
    .Method<int,&X::Do2,double,Opt<int32_t>>("Do2");
```

In the above, Opt is a struct that denotes that the arguments is optional.  The rules for Opt are the same as for C++ function parameters.

This would make a Javascript function along the lines of

```
function X(x,y) {
    // calls C++ X constructor
    //  new X() if x and y are undefined
    // new X(x) if x is an integer and y is undefined
    // new X(x,y) if x is a boolean and y is a number
    // otherwise throw exception
}

X.prototype.Do1 = function() { 
    // Calls X::Do1() only if no arguments are given

}
X.prototype.Do2 = function(x,y) { 
    // Calls X::Do2(x) if y is undefined
    // Calls X::Do2(x,y) if x and y are defined
    // otherwise throw exception
}
```

V8's function call can be abstracted as

```
struct DynamicArguments {
    DynamicValue operator[](int index);
    int Length();
    void Return<T>(T value);
    void ThrowExcpetion();   // call if arguments do not match any method
};
```

where DynamicValue is a strongly typed dyanmic value from V8 (Local if you know V8's API).

I've defined the following functions:

```
bool Is<T>(DynamicValue value);    // return true if value is mapping to C++ type T
T As<T>(DynmaicValue value);       // returns the mapped value, assuming Is<T>(value) is true
```

So there are two function templates that setup the runtime datastructs for matching dynamic calls to static class methods:

```
template<class C, class... Args>
ClassWrapper& ClassWrapper::Constructor();

template<class C,T(C::*TFun)(), class... Args)
ClassWrapper& Method(const char* dynamicFunctionName);
```

and two functions that the V8 engine will call to pass control from Javascript to C++

```
template <class C, class... Args>
void ClassWrapper::Construct(DynamicArguments args);

template <class C, class TRet, T(C::*TFun)(), class... Args>
void ClassWrapper::CallMethod(DynamicArguments args);
```

Construct and CallMethod do the following:

```
Foreach defined override
    foreach arg in args, Arg in Args
        if Arg is Opt<T> then Is<T>(value) must be true
        if Arg is T then Is<T>(value> must be true
    if count<Args>() > args.Length()
         all remaining args must be Opt<T>
    if the above is true for this override,
         do new C(As<Args...>(args...) 
        or TRet value = C->method<Args...>(As<Args...>(args...)
```

where args... is the runtime list of args that match the template pack Args...

Hope that's clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I think you might be best served by distilling your question down into something simpler. It's not really clear to me from scanning the above what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably figured this out over the last few years, but to answer your question,

> The key questions is: Is it possible to type match a template pack
>   against a runtime list of dynamic strong typed values and call the
>   appropriate c++ method/constructor.

... **no**. The moment you entered `DynamicValue` territory, it is no longer compile-time testable, and therefore no longer strongly typed. You can't specialize against something that the compiler has no idea what it actually could be. If it did, it wouldn't be compile-time to begin with but instead be some form of RTTI.

To clarify... not without some sort of branching such as a `switch` statement or `if`/`else if`/`else` or conditionally recursive calling (same thing in this regard as the termination is just the leaf call).